# Python generate a list of classes from folders and subfolders only of a certain type

Tags: python

I have a complicated folder structure that contains many files in folders and sub-folders. I would like to generate a list of all classes that inherit for the "experiment" class so that I can import them. again only if they inherit from the class experiment.

I tried this:

```
import inspect
for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__]):
    if inspect.isclass(obj):
        print(obj)
```

It prints all classes and I suppose I could check them later on **but it doesnt iterate over all folders and subfolders**, just looks in the top level. I could use `os.walk` but is there an easier way?

Comment: To find all the classes, you will have import *everything* in your folder structure. There is no built-in shortcut for that.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan. That is only relevant for classes in modules that have already been imported.

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes. But since importing everything in your folder structure is required anyway...